# How to config Flink Plan Visualizer locally in docker?

Tags: apache-flink

I run Flink in docker.
Exists Flink Plan Visualizer
https://flink.apache.org/visualizer/
Can I use Plan Visualizer locally (when running Flink in docker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much simpler to just use the Flink web UI, which also includes a visualization of the execution plan. That works out of the box, and has a lot more functionality.

But you can use `env.getExecutionPlan()` to get the plan, and then you could copy the visualizer from https://github.com/apache/flink-web/tree/asf-site/visualizer and find some way to host it in your container.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks
But, I need to run the visualizer locally (inside docker)